# Laravel artisan programmatically running command with any parameter without key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-artisan

In my application
, i would like to simulate php artisan command outside CLI, in which i am doing it inside controller.

I am able to get it running with:

```
$execute = Artisan::call($commandPart[0], [
        'companyId' => $commandPart[1]
]);
```

However, it is working if i am specifying it's key for the parameter.
Meanwhile, what i am trying to achieve is to pass in list of command without keyed parameter, as i want it to be flexible.

I tried,

```
$execute = Artisan::call($commandPart[0], [
    $commandPart[1]
]);
```

and

```
$command = 'organization:tree_readjust 1';
$execute = Artisan::call($command);
```

However this both scenario will produce error. 
Any solution for this?

Thank you before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands) `The call method accepts the name of the command as the first argument, and an array of command parameters as the second argument`. so, first make sure `$commandPart[0]` is valid command and you can pass array arguments on second param. ex:

```
$command = 'company:delete';
$companyId = 1;
$commandPart = [$command, $companyId];
$execute = Artisan::call($commandPart[0], [
        'companyId' => $commandPart[1]
]);
```

### Edit:

You cannot call arguments without key. for flexibility I think You can create some logic to make array params and pass it on artisan call `$execute = Artisan::call($command, $params);`

Comment: It is valid. I am wondering the way to pass the parameters without the named/ keyed parameter

Comment: after some trial I think it's cannot running command without key parameter. please give more explanation about your needs, maybe any other solution

Comment: yes..
Exactly like what you said.
I think there is no solution to this case.
We are forced to specify keyed parameters. 

I am thinking a way to make the code more flexible and readable, and simulate what the terminal can do.

Lets say i type "php artisan command_1 param1 param2"

well, in short i am looking for something like forwarding what is typed in my site UI to the terminal

Comment: @BrianRuchiadi I already update my answer. hope that can help you

Answer (score 4):

Dont forget to add the Artisan Facades before using the command in your controller.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
```

Comment: Thanks. nobody else mentioned this somewhere!